# Invalid opcode when installing an AlmaLinux machine in VirtualBox on a Windows 11 pc

Tags: virtualbox, installation, windows-11

I am trying to install an AlmaLinux x64 virtual machine with an ISO disc but when I execute de virtual machine in VirtualBox 6.1 and select install this error shows on the screen:

[image: I]

I tried enabling virtualization on the BIOS, changing the VirtualBox version, directory, AlmaLinux version (I switched from 8.7 to 9.1), and installing the Virtual Box Extension pack for each version. No matter what I did nothing worked. When I tried executing the virtual machine using VirtualBox 7.0.6, the screen went black and nothing happened.

Comment: What's your host OS?

Answer (score 1):

Your Post says Windows 11 Host. That is what I am using here.

Your screen suggests a Video driver conflict between AlmaLinux and Virtual Box.

I had pretty much the same issue with Kali Linux and Hyper-V. Kali provided a Video workaround and it is running fine.

I decided to download and try out AlmaLinux Version 9.1 in VMware Workstation V17. Works just fine.

Options you have:

**(1)** Appeal to AlmaLinux to provide a version that is Virtual Box compliant.

**(2)** Consider a different version of Linux than Alma that is better supported in Virtual Box.

**(3)** Consider changing from Virtual Box to VMware Workstation V17 to run Alma. This does work.

[image: Alma Linux]